# Why does writeStream write the metadata but not the JSON data into the S3 bucket from my Databricks workbook?

Tags: json, amazon-s3, pyspark, databricks

I have been working on a Databricks workbook to read some data, reformat it, and write it into an S3 bucket.

```
csv_data_frame = spark.readStream.format("csv").option("cloudFiles.format", "csv").option("path", "/mnt/data/*.tsv").option("header", "true").option("delimiter", "\t").schema(schema).load()
csv_data_frame.writeStream.format("json").option("path", "/mnt/data/").option("checkpointlocation", "/mnt/data/").start()
```

It does write a metadata file, but no actual json file.  Is my writeStream statement formatted correctly?

Comment: i see input path, output path and checkpoint location all are pointing to the same path? is it correct?

Comment: Yes.  Is that the problem.  It wrote everything out yesterday.  That is what is puzzling.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by changing the **writeStream** command to:

```
csv_data_frame.writeStream.format("json").option("path", "/mnt/data/")
```

I made it too complicated.